# Tentando manipular um JSON com JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Estou tentando pegar um dado do arquivo json e copiar para outro arquivo JSON usando JavaScript, mas eu nunca fiz isso eu tenho esse código JS:

```
let fs = require("fs")
let gravador = []


fs.readFile('index.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == "]") {
      gravador[i] = ""
      console.log(gravador[i])
    }
    else{
      if(data[i]!= ','){
        gravador[i] = data[i]
      }
    }
    
    
  }
    fs.writeFile('writeMe.json', gravador , function(err, result) {
       if(err) console.log('error', err);
     });
   });
```

Quero copiar este JSON para outro arquivo:

```
[
    { 
        "nome": "Fulano",
        "idade": 90 
    },
    { 
            "nome": "Ciclano", 
            "idade": 45 
    }
]
```

Apagando o último caractere `[`, mas o arquivo cria um JSON cheio de vírgulas, assim:

```
[,
,
, , , , ,{, ,
,
, , , , , , , , ,",n,o,m,e,",:, ,",F,u,l,a,n,o,",,
,
, , , , , , , , ,",i,d,a,d,e,",:, ,9,0, ,
,
, , , , ,},,
,
, , , , ,{, ,
,
, , , , , , , , , , , , ,",n,o,m,e,",:, ,",C,i,c,l,a,n,o,",, ,
,
, , , , , , , , , , , , ,",i,d,a,d,e,",:, ,4,5, ,
,
, , , , ,},
,
,,
,
,
,
```

Alguém pode me explicar isso?

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar as funções `JSON.parse` e `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Cara, eu já tentei colocar JSON.parse  ali na hora de atribuir o valor a variável gravador e ficou assim

gravador[i] = JSON.parse(data[i]) 

mas recebi esse erro:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)



e usando:

gravador[i] = JSON.stringify(data[i])

n muda mt coisa essa situação das virgulas apenas ficou tudo em uma linha só

não consigo entender o pq dessas virgulas muito menos como resolver :S

Comment: O objetivo é apenas copiar o conteúdo do arquivo em um novo arquivo?

Comment: Oi Lucas... a ver se percebi bem: tens 2 JSONs e queres adicionar o conteúdo de um deles dentro do outro? podes mostrar o conteúdo do ficheiro de destino?

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer apenas copiar o aquivo para outro:

```
const { createReadStream, createWriteStream } = require('fs');

createReadStream('index.json').pipe(createWriteStream('writeMe.json'));
```

Não faz diferença ser um `json` neste caso.

A partir da versão versão 8.x a função `fs.copyFile` e `copyFileSync` foram adicionadas:

```
const { copyFileSync } = require('fs');

fs.copyFileSync('index.json', 'writeMe.json');
```

---

> **[`fs.copyFile(src, dest[, flags], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback)**
>
> Asynchronously copies `src` to `dest`.

Em tradução livre:

> Copia de forma assíncrona `src` para `dest`.

---

Referência: [**Fastest way to copy file in node.js**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295106/3388148).

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que fazer o parse, para que o JS possa fazer a leitura dos dados sem problemas.

```
fs.readFile('index.json', 'utf8', (error, data) => {

//caso haja erro mostra no terminal
if(error){
    console.log(error)
}

//se está tudo ok... converte o json 
let fileConvert = JSON.parse(data)

//e insere em 'gravador'
gravador.push(fileConvert)
console.log(gravador)

//converter a string para JSON
let dataConverted = JSON.stringify(gravador)

//insere o conteudo do arquivo em outro arquivo JSON
fs.writeFileSync('indexNEW.json', dataConverted, (err, result)=> {
    console.log(result)
})
```

})

Comment: O `return error` leva `error` para onde?

Comment: em caso de erro, será mostrada uma mensagem de erro, vou editar melhor pra vc entender.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na atribuição a variável gravador, quando o loop deixa os índices em branco no array...

Se o objetivo é apagar o último caractere é muito simples, altere as seguintes linhas:

```
let gravador = '';
fs.readFile('index.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  gravador = data.slice(0, -1);
}
```